# Hide view with its all Inner view

Tags: ios, uiview

I have a UIView which has 3 inner UiViews. Lets call it OutterView. So this Outter View has following constraints

- Height is 145 points
- Width equal to superview
- top space to safeview is 8 points

lets now talk about inner view. As I said earlier I have 3 inner views these are align as below

- InnerView1 is attached to top of OuterView with 8 points margin. InnerView1 height = 40 points and width = superview width
- InnerView2 is attached to bottom of InnerView1 with 8 points margin. InnerView2 height = 40 points and width = superview width
- InnerView3 is attached to bottom of InnerView2 with 8 points margin. InnerView3 height = 40 points and width = superview width

now in code when I set the height constraint of superview to 0, it must hide all inner views also. But unfortunately the outview gets hide only. where as inner views stays where they are.

Any help ???

Comment: It sounds like you would benefit greatly from using a UIStackView here. Especially if the "outer" `UIStackView` is inside another `UIStackView`. UIStackView has the property that if you set one of its view to `isHidden = true` it will also set the size of it to 0 so that it is removed from the layout.

Comment: great idea........

Comment: But I am animating the HeightConstraint, so it looks good when it gets to 0 or gets back to 145 point. Can you help me in this ? hiding with animations ?

Comment: You need to set `.clipsToBounds = true` on your "OuterView". If you're using IB / Storyboards, there is a checkbox for that on the view properties.

Comment: wrap the hide line inside UIView.animate ??

Comment: I did it , it does not animate smoothly